Optimization of totally ordered set valued function.
I am familiar with the meaning of optimizing a function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R+}$. However I was just wondering if there's some theory of math explaining how to optimize mapping from $f : \Omega \to \Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is some totally ordered set (for example lexicographic ordering).

Is there a theory or some branch of math studying the optimization of such mapping? If not what is the closest thing known for the study of such problems.

What kind of assumption do we have to make on the range of $f$ in order to talk about "optimizing $f$".



I believe game theory has explored this idea quite intensively as sometimes they only work on preferences rather than some artificial value functions.

What you mean with "artificial value functions"?

some game theorists think everything can be measured by some value functions and work on optimizing those instead. Often times those functions are artificially designed for either analysis purposes or just out of nowhere.
